# how to get this result using oracle query in hierarchical structure

Tags: sql, database, oracle

First, with one collateral, you can borrow money many times from bank. It means that one collateral_num have many loan_num.

Second, you can serve many collaterals to one loan. It means that one loan_num have many collateral_num.

There is a table like this named LOAN.

```
collateral_num | loan_num
-------------------------
 C1            |  A5
 C2            |  A5
 C2            |  A1
 C3            |  A1
 C3            |  A3
 C6            |  A7
 C7            |  A7
```

I want to get minimum collateral_num from LOAN like this table below.
I will explain minium clooateral_num.
There are two group in the first table. One of them is from first row to fifth row. Then, we can find some relationship like  C1→a5→c2→a1→c3→a3 in the first group.
And we discard the nodes including 'a'.
As a result c1 will be minimum collatral num  in c1  c2  c3.(because c1 has the least number.)

In the second group (c6→a7→c7)minimum collatral num will be c6.

```
collateral_num | minimum_collateral_num | loan_num
--------------------------------------------------
 C1            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A3
 C6            |   C6                   |    A7
 C7            |   C6                   |    A7
```

How do I make SQL query to make the result I've told. Any comment will be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like something I'd rather implement coding, not with SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've managed to do this with analytic functions (not elegantly, but nonetheless) -

```
with
grps as(
    select marker
    from(
        select collateral_num,
               loan_num,
               rownum as marker,
               case when lead(loan_num,1) over (order by collateral_num) <> loan_num
                         and lead(collateral_num,1) over (order by collateral_num) <> collateral_num
                    then 1
                    when lead(loan_num,1) over (order by collateral_num) is null
                    then 1
                    else null end as grp
          from  loan
         order by collateral_num
        )
    where grp is not null
       )
, marked as(
    select loan.*, grps.*, row_number() over(partition by marker order by collateral_num) as splitter
    from loan, grps
           )
select  collateral_num,
        min(collateral_num) over (partition by marker) as min_collateral_num,
        loan_num
from    marked y
where   splitter <= marker
    and (splitter > (select max(x.marker) from marked x where x.marker < y.marker)
     or marker = (select min(marker) from marked))
```

See sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfb1a7/40/0